# why is span element not working with this piece of code

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation menu which looks like this:

[image]

I have to split it into three parts (left, center, right).

I have written the html and css code like this:

```
<span id="nav-left-img"></span>
    <ul id="navigation">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About Us</li>
        <li>Products</li>
        <li>Contact Us</li>
    </ul>
<span id="nav-right-img"></span>
```

and here is the css:

```
ul#navigation
{
    background: url('../img/menu-c.png') repeat-x;
    height: 45px;
    clear: both;
    width: 420px;
}
ul#navigation li
{
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
#nav-left-img
{
    background: url('../img/menu-l.png') no-repeat;
    height: 45px;
    width: 10px;
}
```

The `span` does not seems to do the trick; if I use a `div` it works. What is possibly wrong with the code? Is it ok if I use `div` instead of `span` or should I stick with `div` for joining that left and right image? How do I do it with `span`?

Comment: What trick is the span supposed to do exactly? What issues do you get when using a div? What do you want exactly?

Comment: @JamWaffles the span is supposed to join the left and right image to form a single navigation background image, as i have shown in the image i want to split it into three images. i do not get any issue while using the div. but is it not wrong to use div for everything. where in i can use span instead?

Comment: Oh ok :-) My fault for not understanding. I see you like Yammi's answer; it's probably the best way to go.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A *div* is `display:block` by default, a *span* is `display:inline` by default. Width and height cannot be set for `display:inline` elements.

I would recommend to use a `div`.

Comment: i appreciate your suggestion on using a div instead of span. i will be thankful if you justify it. because most of the experts before have suggested me i should not be using div every time.

Comment: Well, there are many people who use *div* all the time - for everything. They forget about lists, tables and paragraphs and when they should be used. *span* and *div* are meant for grouping elements - and the [HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.4) clearly states, that *span* is for inline, *div* is for block-level. So if somebody uses a *span* and tells it to behave like a block-level *div*, wouldn't you agree that this proves a misunderstanding of when to use *div* and *span*?

Answer (score 8):

Maybe try setting the span to display block?

Answer (score 3):

An even neater solution is to use `:after` and `:before` as to completely avoid "useless" HTML:

```
#navigation:before { content: url('../img/menu-1.png'); }
#navigation:after  { content: url('../img/menu-2.png'); }
```

Not IE6 compatible, though...

Comment: this looks so neat, apart from ie6 will it work on all browsers?

Comment: Yup, the `:after` and `:before` are part of the CSS2.1 specifications.

Answer (score 1):

div and span are essentially identical, except for the fact that div defaults to a block level element while span does not. To make it work with span, just add `display: 'block';` to the CSS.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest replacing `span` with `img` like this:
`<img src="img/menu-1.png" alt="" class="nav" />`
and in css
`img.nav{float:left;display:block}`

Comment: Since the image URL is clearly part of the presentation (and not of the content), it should be placed in the CSS and not in the HTML.